# Get .Net Core 3.1 single-file executable version number

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, version

I have a .Net Core application that has been published as a single file executable.  When I run any of the following code from within Visual Studio, I get the expected result:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Installer)).GetName().Version.ToString();
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

But when the above code is run within the published application (in production) it always returns "0.0.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? I created a new project and it seemed to work.

Assuming you're using Visual Studio 2019.

1. Right-click project -> Add -> New Item -> Assembly Information File
2. You will then have a AssemblyInfo.cs file with the assembly version in
3. You then need to ignore the generated assembly version so you need to add GenerateAssemblyInfo with false to your .csproj.
4. Right-click project -> Edit Project File -> Add GenerateAssemblyInfo element like below:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
         <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
         <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
      </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The assembly version should be set in the properties of the project which you're compiling.

Right-click project -> Properties -> Package:

[image]

Comment: As I stated in the original question, when I execute the code in debug mode "from within Visual Studio, I get the expected result".  Therefore, I believe I have set the version number correctly.  By the way, I used the approach suggested by Shoejep.

I think the challenge is not related to setting the version number, rather, it is retrieving the version number when the application is published as a self-contained single-file executable.

The standard way of querying for the version number doesn't seem to work when published as a self-contained single-file executable.

Comment: Further, when I open the DLLs and executable in Windows Explorer and look at the details of the file, the correct version number is there... so again, it's the not that I haven't set the version number correctly.